# Get commit by specific user Git hub API

Tags: php, git, github

That's how I'm getting all commits (using `PHP` and `curl`). First I'm getting last commit:

`https://git.our_company.com/api/v3/projects/xxx/repository/branches/?private_token=xxx`

And second I'm getting previous commits:

```
 https://git.our_company.com/api/v3/projects/xxx/repository/commits/?per_page=100&sha={$sha}&private_token={$token};
```

But it takes time and resources filtering that commit by author AFTER getting them

[Here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) mentioned that we can specify author (?). **updated** I tried to add `&author=name`, but no changes. I can't get it to work.

As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688004/github-api-commits-by-author) this feature is deprecated.

Comment: Where's the `author=<loginOrEmail>` part in the URI? That's what you need to add to filter commits by author (according to the docs)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I tried it of course, no changes I saw in result